# Does digitalocean provide admin panel like Plesk to manage Windows VPS?

Tags: windows, iis, digital-ocean, vps

I have Windows VPS with a local hosting provider. Right now I have four .Net applications hosted on this VPS. I want to migrate my all applications to digitalocean.com. As I know Digitalocean provides VPS and they name it droplets. 
In their documents, they say we provide unmanaged VPS which means I have to take care of software installation)(s).

Before starting this migration I have these questions in my mind.

- Does it provide an admin panel like Plesk to manage Windows droplet?
- Can I manage to deploy multiple sites on single droplet through an admin panel?
- Does it include Windows server license in their [package](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) or I have to
  pay separately to create a Windows VPS? I am not even sure if they
  provide Windows server ready or I have to install Windows Server OS too
  ..... :)

Answers to these questions will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You could just ask Digital Ocean directly?

Comment: I tried reaching them but they have not responded so far :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently, DigitalOcean only supports Linux and Linux-based OS's. You can try to use something like https://steemit.com/tech/@hursh/tutorials-how-to-install-windows-on-digital-ocean but it is not confirmed feature.